# Escape a forward slash in attribute name of XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, apache-camel

I am converting the XML String to Document before I operate on it. I receive the XML from a third party API.

This is my XML

```
<Student full/part="part" name="Some Name" dob="2000-08-01" totalMarks="565" science="9" maths="8" registration="987654"  class="distinction" />
```

This is the exception I get

```
org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value  due org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 64; Attribute name "full" associated with an element type "Student" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

Now I don't have definition and I just retrieve attribute values from this XMLs. ie tomorrow this  element type might be Teacher from Student but I just put together values of attributes like registration,class and even 'full/part'.

I would like to know by which  org.w3c.dom.Document tolerates this forward slash in this XML attribute name of given element type.

Comment: This is not `xml`. Where did you get this string from ? May be it is intended to be a `String`

Comment: @svasa do you mean attributes names of any element cannot have forward slash ??

Comment: @VirajNalawade: Correct, forward slash is not allowed in attribute names.  See [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44057262/290085) for details.  You might use `-` or `_` instead, or you might consider `full="true"` or other renaming possibilities.

Comment: @kjhughes thanks .. even I have not worked on any XML with similar attribute names.. but I have very little control on XML provided to me..

Comment: You're still missing the point: ***it's not XML that's provided to you.***  That's not being pedantic; it's be pragmatic.  You cannot use XML libraries or tools to process that textual data.  Tell the provider to fix it or provide an ecosystem of standards and tools to parse and process it (good luck with that).

Comment: Where did this corrupt XML come from? It's unusable and you should go to whoever sent it and tell them to mend their ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) of an XML [attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Attribute) (or of an XML [element](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#d0e2130))

> `[5] Name ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*`

cannot contain a `/` character:

> `[4] NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6]
>                         | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D]
>                         | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] 
>                         | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] 
>                         | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]`
>
> `[4a] NameChar     ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7
>                         | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]`

There is no escape mechanism that would allow otherwise.